# How does typescript syntax let { var } = var work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn how to use electron with Angular and got confused with syntax I saw from the Electrogram app.

Link: https://github.com/onehungrymind/electrogram

In the **app.ts** file of electrogram's project, I saw the syntax:

```
import { remote, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
...
let {dialog} = remote;
```

I think it's referring to `dialog: Electron.Dialog;` in the projects **index.d.ts** at path *typings/globals/github-electron* although I really don't know yet how this is happening. (I'm also really new to typescript).

If this was globally declared shouldn't it be at least `Electron.CommonElectron.dialog`?
 How can the compiler just know right away what we are referring to by just saying `let { dialog }`?

Any explanation on this would be greatly appreciated as I really have no idea whats going on.

Comment: `The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: Yes, but it's not like the imports have concatenated with app.ts. All imports have been obj vars. The list of imports is shown below: let filters = require('./../assets/data/filters.json');

import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ViewChild, Input, Component, ChangeDetectorRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CanvasService } from './canvasService';
import { remote, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import { writeFile } from 'fs';

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript, or Angular, or Electron. It's just plain old JavaScript (ES6).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is destructuring. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Essentially, pick one property out of an object and create a new variable for it.

```
let a = { x: 1, y: 2 };
let { x } = a;
console.log(x) // 1
```

Comment: No. That's not the word you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been looking around the typescript gitbook thinking it was some sort of special way to load a typings module haha.